# Cropping and Reformatting PDF Pages in Acrobat

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have a pdf file with 8 pages in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC. I want to remove the content on the top half of the first page, then move all the other content up. When I try and delete the content, it leave remnants, when I crop the pdf, it leaves the first page half the size of the others.

How can I crop the page, then reset the pages to all be even A4 size starting with the kept content at the top?

Like how deleting text in word moves all the other text up to the top.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer : You cannot.

From Adobe Help page
[Edit text in PDFs](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/edit-text-pdfs.html)
section "Edit text - change, replace, or delete":

> When you edit text, the text in the paragraph reflows within its text box to accommodate the changes. Each text box is independent, and inserting text in one text block does not push down an adjacent text box or reflow to the next page.

Long answer: You will need to do the work yourself, moving manually text between
the pages. Not really feasible.

The only good solution is
to update the source file from which the PDF was created.
Otherwise, try converting the PDF to another format, for example Microsoft Word,
editing it in that format and then re-creating the PDF.

Comment: That's annoying, but thank you for letting me know!